# GCE cluster all nodes NotReady

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, google-compute-engine

`kubectl get nodes` all nodes status NotReady.

What is the actions should I take to diagnose and fix the issue?

I tried `kubectl drain` status changed to `NotReady,SchedulingDisabled` and then `kubectl uncordoned` changed back to NotReady.

Master version  1.4.6

Comment: What version are you running? `NotReady` is not related to using `drain`.

Comment: Master version 
1.4.6

Comment: Can you ssh into the nodes using `gcloud compute ssh`? If you can, then getting the logs from the controller manager, and kubelet can help. The quickest way to get back up and running may be just resetting the instances, but I'd suggest you get the logs first to ensure we can figure out what's happening.

Comment: What is the node version you're running? Is it the same (1.4.6?)

Comment: How to get the logs? I sshed to node, and run `systemctl` in the output there was a line with error: kube-node-configuration.service           loaded failed failed    Configure kubernetes node

Comment: The log files should be under `/var/log/*.log`. The relevant ones may be `kube-controller-manager.log` on the master, and `kubelet.log` on the other nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I you run `kubectl get nodes` you'll get the nodes ids.

Then usually, you may find relevant infos about such problems by running `kubectl describe node node_id` (`node_id`being the one you've seen listed by the previous command)

Comment: did it helped ?